# Is Possible to load springboot yaml properties in angular8 component

Tags: thymeleaf, angular8, spring-boot-2

i want to access springboot yaml property into angular component,
project structure is springboot2.1, angular8 and thymeleaf templates for mvc.

Comment: Why do you want to access yaml property in angular component?